# Passa parâmetros via post para Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um CSHTML onde os campos irão se transformar em parâmetros, que serão passados via post para um método existente em uma controller. Como eu faço isso? Estou pesquisando, mas ainda tenho dúvidas de como passar, como o método vai entender que vem de um cshtml.

Comment: tens tudo dentro de um formulário?

Comment: Post os trechos relevantes de seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos modos de enviar parâmetro via post para o seu `controller` é encapsulando seus parâmetros dentro de um formulário no `CSHTML` do tipo `POST` e enviando-os através do submit.

Você pode utilizar os *helpers* do **MVC** para isto.

Exemplo

Em seu Model:

```
 public class PessoaModel
{

    public string Nome {get;set;} 
    public string Senha {get;set;}
}
```

Em sua View CSHTML

```
@model PessoaModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar","PessoaController", FormMethod.POST))
 {
    @Html.Label("Nome"):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Nome) <br />
    @Html.Label("Senha"):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Senha)
 }
```

Em seu Controller

```
public class PessoaController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Salvar (PessoaModel model)
    {
        //Seu codigo quando a requisição post acontecer
    }    
}
```

Você também pode enviar informações `POST` através de um formulário sem a utilização de um model, utilizando os *helpers* sem a terminação for, e tendo em seu *controller* o parâmetro do mesmo nome passado no parâmetro do *helper*.

Por exemplo:

Em seu CSHTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar","PessoaController", FormMethod.POST))
 {
    @Html.Label("Nome"):
    @Html.TextBox("Nome") <br />
    @Html.Label("Senha"):
    @Html.TextBox("Senha")
 }
```

Em seu Controller

```
public class PessoaController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Salvar(string nome, string senha)
    {
        //Seu codigo quando a requisição post acontecer
    }    
}
```

Comment: Um dúvida. Tenho minha cshtml Index(Home), mas os parâmetros vem da Home e vão ser executados na controller Passo e não na HomeController. Isso não tem problema?

Comment: Todos os controllers do mvc precisam terminar com o nome Controller. Por exemplo, PassoController (pelo que entendi). E sim, você pode alterar o controller e a action dentro do @Html.BeginForm alterando os dois primeiros parâmetros, mas dependendo do contexto e de sua implementação isso pode ficar desorganizado.